# Image and Video responsiveness not working

Tags: html, css, laravel

I want an image and an embeded youtube video to be responsive but it's not. My code looks like the following. I tried using `max-width: 100%;` too but still nothing.

You can see my code for the image and the video below.
**image**

```
<div class="infographic responsive">
        <img src="{{ asset('images/infographic.png') }}" alt="" width="800px" height="auto">
</div>
```

**video**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="video_text">
 <h2 id="video_heading">
   Hello World,
 </h2>
 <p id="video_heading_text">
    Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
 </p>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="video">
  <iframe class="video" src="{{ url('https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXXX') }}" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

The following is my **style.css** 
**css file**

```
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.infographic {
    width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
#intro_video {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
#video_text {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#video_heading{
    font-family: Signika;
}
#video_heading_text {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.video {
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have a width attribute on your image and on your video too change those to 100 or remove them entirely

Comment: You have already added fixed width in your image and iframe width="800px", width="560"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it responsive remove fixed width from `img` and `iframe` and add `width: 100%`

```css
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.infographic {
    width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
#intro_video {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
#video_text {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#video_heading{
    font-family: Signika;
}
#video_heading_text {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.video {
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="infographic responsive">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-during-sunset-beautiful-natural-260nw-407021107.jpg" width="100%"  height="auto">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="video_text">
     <h2 id="video_heading">
       Hello World,
     </h2>
     <p id="video_heading_text">
        Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
     </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="video">
    <iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fd8okLRFUeQ" width="100%" height="315px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
```